# DLNA server on windows 8.1 block control features over LAN

Tags: networking, port, windows-8.1, windows-firewall, dlna

I stay at a hotel-apartment complex so my connection is public since it is shared.

I recently installed the Kooraroo Media streaming software on my Computer, I use it to stream to my other devices over LAN.

I found a problem in it.
It does have the feature to block new devices but it also has a web interface. The web interface can be accessed from any device on the network without any limitation or security. But there is an added option in the link like this: IP address: port number /html

I can see on the firewall connections list that this software uses over 30 ports. So I assume that at least one of them can control the web interface feature and maybe more than one. But it takes too long to test each one.

I also tried to edit the host file to block it. I managed to block internet websites but not this one. Maybe it needs a different setting for that.
I did testing from the same machine and from a remote one and it failed on both cases.

So is there an easy way to find a way to block a part of the program and not all of it?

[The List of ports on the firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfwSM.jpg)

I added the list in the attachment...

Answer (score 0):

The free 32-bit version 2.4.0 of Kooraroo DLNA Media server has the web interface option disabled by default.

So this issue is closed.